# TSQL Date conversion Trouble

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a table I am getting from a 3rd party. The date in the column is in a format I havent seen before.

Here is an example of the date: `2013MO01` This date is Jan, 2013 with MO meaning Month 1

Any easy suggestions on getting the date from that field in the database ?

Comment: Where is the day? And time (if any)?

Comment: There is none, all the colum shows is the Month and year which would be all I need but not sure how to convert that in a statement

Comment: Then correct me if I'm wrong but SUBSTRING function should do the job here, no? You can't convert to `datetime` obviously but you can get year and month out of string segments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @chrono mentioned, you can use SUBSTRING, for example:

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(100) = '2013MO01'
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@t, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@t, 7, 2) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
```

Or just replacing the *MO* string:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@t, 'MO', '-') + '-01' AS DATETIME)
```